# Add text dynamically to TextInput

Tags: react-native

I would like to add a UnicodeText viewed inside the textInput when I click a button.

I've tried to create a state {text} then add the UnicodeText to the state text.

The text with the added text is properly shown in the console.log(). Not in the textInput.

```
import { Icon, Input } from "react-native-elements";
var emoji = require("node-emoji");

export default class MainViewMessageInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: "",
      username: "",
      visible: false,
      showEmoticons: false
    };
  }

  _sendMessage() {
    var texte = this.state.text;
    this.setState({ text: "" });
    console.log(this.state.text);
  }

  _addEmoji() {
    this.state.text = this.state.text + emoji.get("green_heart");
    const emojiChar = this.state.text + emoji.get("green_heart");
    this.setState({ text: emojiChar });
    console.log(this.state.text);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Input
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          leftIcon={
            <TouchableHighlight
              onPress={() => {
                this._addEmoji();
              }}
              style={styles.icon}
            >
              <Icon size={40} color="#d2d3d5" name="mood" />
            </TouchableHighlight>
          }
          rightIcon={
            <Icon
              reverse
              onPress={() => this.setState({ visible: true })}
              color="#00b5ec"
              name="send"
              size={23}
            />
          }
          rightIconContainerStyle={{ marginRight: -7 }}
          leftIconContainerStyle={{ marginLeft: 0 }}
          inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
          inputStyle={styles.input}
          placeholder="Write your message ..."
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          multiline={true}
          editable={true}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

you can push textinput into array in runtime so u get textinput dynamically

Answer (score 0):

for input add field value={this.state.text}

[reference](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#value)

Answer (score 0):

remove `this.state.text = this.state.text + emoji.get("green_heart");` from `_addEmoji()`